# Spaces in wikimedia templates

Tags: templates, hyperlink, whitespace, mediawiki

I'm working on a MediaWiki-generated Wiki, and want to build a template that would link me to a French Wikipedia article. I have this :

```
[http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{{1|}}} {{#if:{{{2|}}}|{{{2|}}}|{{{1|}}}}}]
```

Logic being :

```
{{Wpfr|article name|alternate name (if needed)}}
```

Thing is, if the article name has spaces in it, it breaks, keeping the first word as {{{1}}} and putting the rest in {{{2}}}.

I'd like to find a way to be able to use spaces in {{{1}}} without breaking the links. That way :

```
{{Wpfr|Greg Weisman}}
```

would automatically link to the article on Greg Weisman and display "Greg Weisman".
I've tried using :

```
[http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{{art|}}} {{#if:{{{2|}}}|{{{2|}}}|{{{art|}}}}}]
{{Wpfr|art=article name}}
```

(even replacing the 2s by 1s) to no avail.

The Wiki admin part hasn't been updated in a while so the Interwiki table can't be updated and I can't use the "replace" function either.

I'm new to Wikicoding, so I'm sorry if the answer is very simple.

Thanks !

Edit : the MediaWiki version is 1.13.5

Answer (score 1):

Mediawiki has a [magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data) for handeling encoding of url:

> {{urlencode:data|style}}

`{{urlencode:Greg Weisman|PATH}}` will return:

> Greg%20Weisman

Change your template with:

```
[http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{urlencode:{{{1|}}}|PATH}} {{#if:{{{2|}}}|{{{2|}}}|{{{1|}}}}}]
```

Comment: I just tried, but instead of %20, it gives me +, which doesn't make sense according to the documentation about magic words...(I tried with QUERY and WIKI with the same result). Probably has to do with the fact that the version of my MediaWiki is 1.13.5 and this word is for 1.17 and more.

Comment: So you are using a version that is more than 10 years old... Maybe try {{anchorencode: bla bla}}.

Comment: The admin set it up, then life came barging in so he didn't have time to maintain it. Tried anchorencode right after you showed me the link. Works when only spaces are involved, anything else (",", "(", ")", etc.) and it breaks.

Comment: Indeed, mediawiki's 1.13.5 urlencode function is directly mapped to the php function of the same name... Which returns a + for space... Maybe you could try some javascript...

Comment: Is it easy to do, from my position (as non-admin)? To be honest, I know absolutely nothing about javascript.

Comment: From what I've seen, the javascript page has been locked by the admin, so that's a no-go as well.